# HP Laptop not detecting headset microphone

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

I have a Razer Kraken X headset and it includes s microphone.

Whenever I plug into my laptop, the audio is working but the microphone is not working properly. Seems like my PC doesn't recognize the microphone. I open up device manager and it only shows `Microphone Array`.

I'm using combo jacks. Anyone know how can I fix this issue?

[My device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqLot.png)

[My sound setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/300Tf.png)

[My laptop port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Rc7.jpg)

[My jacks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaEfJ.jpg)

Comment: combo jax?? You mean jacks? That's where 9/10 issues are, wrong cables.

Comment: Im using one single jax to plug into my laptop. But it doesnt work. But when i plug in to another laptop it work. [The jax](https://ibb.co/KFnyTz9) , [My laptop port](https://ibb.co/PZhwhyw)

Comment: Are you converting 4 pole to 3 pole? Your headphone jack appears 4 pole but the extension cable appears to have 3 poles? What if you plug the headphone directly to the audio port without any extension cables?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use a splitter as an extension. That's not going to work.

Comment: Nono, i directly plugin the jack to my laptop without the spliter. But it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before, and I've been trying to solve it for a long period now. I tried so many things. In the end, I found out that what I was lacking was not the audio driver, but a piece of software called audio manager. Since I and you have a universal port (one port for both mic and speaker) the programs that solved this issue were the kind of programs that gives a pop-up message when you plug in the cable and ask you to select the device you plugged (e.g. speaker, microphone, headphone without mic, headset with mic, or line in), so you should first check if you have any of the below software because one might already be available on your laptop, and if not, then download and instal one of them (check to see which is compatable with your system):

1. Realtek audio manager
2. Realtek audio console
3. Waves maxxaudio

If you already have the programs or if you had to download it, there is an option (a checkbox) in the software setting (under advanced settings or jack settings or jack info) that allows the necessary pop-up. Make sure it is enabled.